# windows internal database consuming a lot of memory

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have a trial windows 2008 r2
with sqlexpress 2008 installed on it

but he also has his one native
sql server for **sbs monitoring**
and a instance called **Windows Internal Database** which is consuming almost all the available RAM (4GB)

I've shut down all these services and the server/iis (my site) work without them, are they needed to be there for some reason ?

Comment: I'm doing a little tour of questions that relate to WID on Windows 2008 to note that Windows 2012 changes the pipe to `\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Internal Database is a (sort-of) "embedded" version of SQL Server Express, which is available as a Windows component in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2; it's only used by some Microsoft applications, and only if you configure them to use it instead of a "true" SQL Server instance.

The applications that can use WID are presently two: Windows SharePoint Services and Windows Server Update Services (WSUS).

Are you running one or both of them on that server? You probably are, otherwise WID would not be running; if you don't use them, disable (or, better, uninstall) them, and that WID instance will not bother you anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the Windows Internal Database gets installed when you do a standalone install of SharePoint. I can't really tell you whether or not you need them but if you install SQL Server Management Studio on the computer you can connect to the instance and see if there are any databases on the instance. The internal database product is really just a minimal version of SQL Server. If there are databases there then you probably need to keep it, but if you right click on the server in SQL Server Management Studio and go to Properties you can set a maximum memory setting so it doesn't consume all the memory on the server.

To connect to the Windows Internal Instance you need to use the server name below, and this has only worked locally for me.

```
\\.\pipe\mssql$microsoft##ssee\sql\query
```